# E muet cas particulier

Tags: poésie

Bonjour à tous,
J’ai une question à propos du comptage de pieds dans certains cas particuliers :

- Si l’on prend la phrase « harmonie et fête » de manière orale on prononcerait har-mo-nie-et-fête, mais la règle du e muet ferait plutôt har-mo-niet-fête non ?
- un e suivi du mot être comme par exemple dans « faible être » sera-t-il muet ou non ? Compterons nous fai-bleê-tre ou fai-ble-ê-tre ?
- faisons nous l’hiatus dans la phrase « parmi eux » ?
- de meme faisons nous l’hiatus sur une phrase telle que « établie individuellement » ?

Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Si l’on prend la phrase « harmonie et fête » de manière orale on prononcerait har-mo-nie-et-fête, mais la règle du e muet ferait plutôt har-mo-niet-fête non ?

**Non** car -niet- compte pour deux syllabes : -ni- et -et-. De plus, le *e* étant précédé d'une voyelle, donc il n'apporte rien (phonétiquement).

> un e suivi du mot être comme par exemple dans « faible être » sera-t-il muet ou non ? Compterons nous fai-bleê-tre ou fai-ble-ê-tre ?

Le *e* est élidé (compte pour 0 syllabe) lorsqu'il est suivi d'une voyelle. Donc **on dira un fai-blê-tre ou fai-blêtre** (si on se situe à la fin du vers).

> faisons nous l’hiatus dans la phrase « parmi eux » ? / de meme faisons nous l’hiatus sur une phrase telle que « établie individuellement » ?

Pas de hiatus en poésie, donc **on dira par-mi-eux**.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour vos réponses très claires ! 
Et simplement de même qu’avec le ê, un et e suivi d’un é ou d’un è s’élide c’est bien cela ?

Comment: Oui tout à fait ! N’hésite pas à accepter la réponse si tu la trouves satisfaisante.